# Error en el literal del tooltip de la pestaña preguntas sin responder

Tags: bug, estado-completado

Como podeis ver si paso por encima de la pestaña `Preguntas sin responder` sale

> Preguntas sin ningún voto a favor

Cuando deberia usarse algo parecido al literal que al lado:

> Preguntas sin responder <strike>[con etiquetas]</strike>

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La traducción correcta es *Preguntas que no tienen respuestas con votos a favor*. Corregido, se actualizará en la próxima compilación. ¡Gracias!